# Uploading image to Django database raises TypeError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, python-imaging-library

I am having trouble uploading image paths into my Django database. When I try to add data without the eventImage field, it works fine. But when I upload anything to the eventImage field, it says:

```
TypeError at /admin/events/event/add/
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/events/event/add/
Django Version: 3.2.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not tuple
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/posixpath.py, line 374, in abspath
```

I've put relevant code snippets below. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong!

In my **settings.py** file:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'events',
]
```

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media'),
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

In my **events.py** file:

```
from django.db import models

class Event(models.Model):
    venueName = models.TextField()
    artistName = models.TextField()
    eventName = models.TextField()
    time = models.TextField()
    date = models.TextField()
    length = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    eventImage = models.ImageField(
        upload_to='media/', blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.eventName
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your end comma `,` please remove it like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Let me know if there is any more issue

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked brilliantly.